# Need assistance regarding objective-c and opps concept

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

Currently I am working on messaging app, which send text messages, image and audio files.

Files get uploaded on http server, for downloading and uploading I am using NSURLConnection.

When user tap download button I extract out the cell of table view and add progressview as a subview like this

**In header file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIProgressView *progress;
```

**In Class File my download method**

```
progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
        progress.trackTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        progress.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 160, 30);
        progress.progress = 0.0;
        [cell addSubview:progress];
```

**When data is received this NSURLConenction delegate method get called**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(imgUpload)
    {
        NSLog(@"UPLOAD");
    }
    else
    {
        [self.resourceData appendData:data]; 
        NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[self.resourceData length]];

        [self.progress setProgress:[resourceLength floatValue] / [self.filesize floatValue] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If there are more then one file and every time user tap on the download button this whole code will execute and progressview will be added to that cell, but all are referred through **progress** variable. **How every individual progressview is identified uniquely**. If I try to download three files all progressview indicate there own progress and works fine.

Please clear this concept.

**Yes under the hood data is messing up, I tried to download audio and image file together but ended up with corrupt files.**

**Please provide a example how to solve this issue.**

Comment: Could the cell itself not handle the download? Therefore the each cell would be its own delegate?

Comment: When the user starts multiple downloads, is there really just the progress indicators that are messed up? Don't you mess up your self.resourceData as well? If I were you I would introduce several data objects, one for each download. Those objects initiate the download and therefore receive the didReceiveData messages individually. You could initiate these objects with references to the table so that they can update their related progress bars. If you do that within table view cells, be aware that the cell may scroll off the screen and may be re-used during download progress!

Comment: Ross, what whould happen then when the cell is being re-used? Especiall when there is a download started too on one of the re-used cell objects? You could of course simply not apply the reusing-mechanism.

Comment: @HermannKlecker very true. My point was that the `cell data model` or the datasource __of the cell view__ should be acting as delegate and not the table view controller. Indeed there would be an issue with the cell view being reused. When the cell view is no longer being displayed it should resign its self as delegate to whatever, but it does sound like the cell view would need to be delegate to *something* unless the OP goes down the route of notifications.  _p.s. flag me with @Ross so I get a notification : )_

Comment: @Ross When message is received it shows the download button on uitableviewcell, I add the action on button like this: [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; ... In downloadImage method I extract the cell of this button -(void)downloadImage:(UIButton )myBtn { UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell)[myBtn superview];.............. and then I add progressview and start download with the received url through NSURLConnection…

Comment: @Ross downloading is handled by NSURLConnection Delegate methods.

Comment: @Ross here is the memory address of three progressViews through NSLog(@"%p", progress); 0x1f13bd10, 0x1f13cb30, 0x1f169580.

Comment: @Ross I want to know how its working and only UIProgressView *progress; variable is referring all of them, How they are individually identified and updating individually or under the hood some mess is going on?

Comment: @HermannKlecker please view the comments.

Comment: @Ross what is the correct approach?

Comment: @sweetJenny, Ross is right. You cannot refer to 3 individual progress vies within only one instance variable. Nor can you receive the data of 3 requests in parallel using this pattern. You will have to create one object for each download that acts as delegate for receiving the data and process it. These objects could 'know' in which of the rows the progress bar is displayed. They shold check whether the related cell is visible, fetch the cell object and update its progress bar.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I request to please provide a small example in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SweetJenny you question is not really specific enough to provide a bit of example code for (at least imo or afaik). You have a structural issue. Try making you own Object which can download your data. Then allow that object to have a delegate which will notify a receiver of download progress (as HermannKlecker says above).

Comment: @Ross My specific question is How to download N number of files asynchronously with progress using NSURLConnection? Thanks you.

Comment: @Ross Is Using GCD can be another good solution?

Comment: @SweetJenny... by having multiple objects which each own their own NSURLConnection.